# What's the param (`_`) in a function?

Tags: python

I saw a function like bellow, I don't know the `_` meaning.

```
def child_handler(signum, _):
    logging.warn('received SIGQUIT, doing graceful shutting down..')
```

what's the `_` there?

---

but, however, if we ignore the `_`, why we need there an ignored param?

Comment: means to ignore the value, similar to the way you would use it in a loop

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)

Comment: @SmartManoj you can flag for duplicate, not just leave a comment.

Comment: while this can look a duplicate, I still can't get the point of using `_` as a function param. Can anyone explain?

Comment: To answer as to why put a unused argument : this function is probably meant to be used in a context where it will be passed two arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It essentially is a way of `ignoring` the value of the variable, and we don't want to use it down the line.

Another way of thinking is that it is a placeholder for the value that will be ignored

```
def func(a, b):

    return a,b

#I care about both return values
c,d = func(2,3)

#I don't care about the second returned value, so I put a _ to ignore it
c, _ = func(2, 3)
```

Another good use case of this is when you are running a for loop, but don't care about the index.

```
for _ in range(10):
    #do stuff
```

Even for functions, it acts like a don't care variable

```
def func(a, _):
    print(a)

func(1, 5)
```

The output will be `1`

Comment: why we need there an ignored param in a function?

Comment: Updated, please check! Actually I am also unsure why we need a ignored param, but could you point out where did you get `def child_handler(signum, _):` from ?

Comment: Why will the output of `func(1, 5)` be `5`, when the second parameter is ignored? It prints `1` for me...

Answer (score 1):

the `_` variable is just a way to say that it's not going to be used further down the line.

Basically, you don't care what the name is because it'll never be referenced.

Answer (score -1):

The underscore `_` in Python can be used for different cases. In this case it means that the second argument of the `child_handler` function is ignored (so-called "Don't care").